# Split int to separate digits so as to loop over each digit

Tags: go

Am new to GoLang. So am doing leetcode problems each day of which one was to Subtract the Product and Sum of Digits of an Integer. For this initially I thought of splitting the integer to individual numbers and then add / multiply all of them to get the output. But was unable to do that as I currently do not understand the type conversions adequately. After many trials and errors, I gave up on that approach and used the divide & modulo to get the last numbers and getting the output. Here's what I did:

```
func subtractProductAndSum(n int) int {
    sum, prod := 0, 1
    for {
        if n < 10 {
            sum += n
            prod *= n
            break
        }
        sum += n % 10
        prod *= n % 10
        n = n / 10
    }
    return prod - sum
}
```

This worked but among other answers I found one which worked, based on my first approach (Splitting and conquering), which was:

```
func subtractProductAndSum(n int) int {
    p := 1
    s := 0
    
    strN := strconv.Itoa(n)    
    for _, val := range strN {
        intVal := int(val - '0')
        p = p * intVal
        s = s + intVal   
    }
    
    return p - s   
}
```

In this approach I could not understand `intVal := int(val - '0')`. It certainly gets the desired output. I think `val` is being type casted to `int` but I am unable to understand what is  `- '0'` helping with.

Hoping somebody could help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `strN` contains a string value which is same as `n`. `val` variable in `for loop` is a `character` type data not a `int` digit and it's definitely not being type casted into `int`.

The variable `val` may contain any of the following character `{'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'}`.

So, if you subtract `'0'` from any of the digit character, you will get difference between `'0'` and that `digit` which is actually the `int` value you are looking for.

The subtract is basically the difference between the `ASCII` values of the two characters.

For example, if you subtract `'0'` from `'5'`, you will get `5` which is integer value. 
`ASCII` value of `'5'` and `'0'` is `53` and `48`. So, `'5' - '0'` is actually `53 - 48` whch is `5`.

This is how the type conversion in your code works.

Comment: ohhhh, thanks so much for the detailed answer. Understood.